# Multi-pages interface of a game in Asp.net - Need some guidance

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am planing to make the game page of my quiz asp.net project, I've build already all the game-logic on server-side.

The game it's a quiz based on user answer timing and give a score according to the right answer and the timing.

A bit like **SongPop** game on FaceBook, Android and iOS.
(See an [Example](http://youth.be/EGXVna_1xsE))

I want a cool user interface and planing to use timers of 10 sec for each question, I would like to make each question appearing without refreshing the page at all and use partial-page update of AJAX or maybe JQuery features. I thought about using the **MultiView** asp server control or **Wizard** asp server control, but wanted to know if there are better alternatives that are working well with JavaScript, CSS transition animations and events (using eventually JQuery)

I saw a nice JQuery thing called **Multi-Page** but it's for mobile. Any equivalent thing for desktop application?

I am open to learn new things so feel free to advice me your suggestions!
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

**You can check out zurb foundation framework which will work on mobile, tab and desktop**

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html